# R sum two columns with condition on third column

Tags: r, sum, sumifs

I have a data frame like:

```
user_name started_at          session_time_min    task_completed timediff
ABC       2018-03-02 18:00:00                1                 3       NA
ABC       2018-03-02 19:00:00             1036                18        1
ABC       2018-03-03 12:00:00                6                10       17
ABC       2018-03-04 21:00:00                0                 1       33
ABC       2018-03-05 16:00:00              143                61       19
ABC       2018-03-05 18:00:00               12                18        2
ABC       2018-03-05 19:00:00               60                94        1
ABC       2018-03-05 20:00:00               20                46        1
ABC       2018-03-09 15:00:00                0                 1       91
```

I want to sum session_time_min and task_completed  with previous row if timediff = 1

Want output like:

```
user_name started_at          session_time_min    task_completed 
ABC       2018-03-02 18:00:00             1037                21       
ABC       2018-03-03 12:00:00                6                10       
ABC       2018-03-04 21:00:00                0                 1       
ABC       2018-03-05 16:00:00              143                61       
ABC       2018-03-05 18:00:00               92               158        
ABC       2018-03-09 15:00:00                0                 1
```

Any help will highly be appricated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `for` loop to help you out especially if you want to use base R.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  if (is.na(data[i,5])){
    data[i+1,3] <- data[i+1,3] + data[i,3]
    data[i+1,4] <- data[i+1,4] + data[i,4]
  } else {}
}

data <-  na.omit(data)
```

This code runs through each row in your dataframe and checks if the value in column 5 (timediff) is a `NA`. If it is an NA it adds (for the 2 columns you want positioned at 3 and 4) it to the row below (which will be `i+1`)

Comment: Thanks for answering! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 1):

Make a group counter using `cumsum` and then use that to subset the identifier columns and `rowsum` the value columns:

```
grp <- cumsum(!dat$timediff %in% 1)
#[1] 1 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 6
cbind(
  dat[match(unique(grp), grp), c("user_name","started_at")],
  rowsum(dat[c("session_time_min","task_completed")], grp)
)
#  user_name         started_at session_time_min task_completed
#1       ABC 2018-03-0218:00:00             1037             21
#3       ABC 2018-03-0312:00:00                6             10
#4       ABC 2018-03-0421:00:00                0              1
#5       ABC 2018-03-0516:00:00              143             61
#6       ABC 2018-03-0518:00:00               92            158
#9       ABC 2018-03-0915:00:00                0              1
```

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful. cbind gave me object as list. so I used cbind.data.frame instead of cbind to directly get the object as the data frame.

Comment: @Vinod - I'm a bit confused as to how that would happen - if `dat` is a `data.frame`, then `cbind(dat, ...)` etc will automatically call `cbind.data.frame` anyway. Were you starting with a `matrix` object?